# Linux OS-level key chord

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

On my keyboard a few keys like <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd>, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> are difficult to press and I would like to avoid using my pinky for such high frequency keys. Is there a program I can run that intercepts all keystrokes and replacing certain chords such as "df" (i.e. not limited to a modifier key and a non-modifier) with the appropriate keysym?

Comment: Are you sure working the issue around is worth it? I'm not sure how many times you press Enter, Esc and Ctrl in a day, but it seems that getting a new keyboard would save you a lot of time and effort.

Answer (score -1):

Not a direct answer, but sticky-keys can help ease your strain as part of the problem is the need to hold modifier key at the same time as regular key. (XFCE: Accessibility/Keyboard/Use_sticky_keys)

Comment: Can you please provide more details. It is impossible to understand how `sticky keys` would be a solution without an explanation

Comment: @Prasanna Edited